# Make an app to upload image to server in codenameone

Tags: java, android, image, codenameone

I was using android studio for last three months  but when I moved to codename one I cant get a idea as everything seems so different and I don't know where to begin. I want to choose image from gallery on button click and upload it to a server.Can you help me shai ?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually much simpler than Android:

```
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.addData("myFileName", fullPathToFile, "text/plain")
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

Taken from the JavaDoc here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html